# Cuda cuLaunchHostFunc equivalent in python libs

Tags: callback, cuda, numba, pycuda

Using Python to drive CUDA, I want to schedule a Python host function asynchronous in a stream that runs after a kernel and memory copy has been taken place.

Is there an equivalent to the CUDA C++ function `CUresult cuLaunchHostFunc(CUstream hStream, CUhostFn fn, void* userData)` in one of the Python libs (`PyCuda`, `Numba`, ...)?

The Driver API function is here in the [CUDA docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gab95a78143bae7f21eebb978f91e7f3f)

Comment: What do you mean by "host function" in this context?

Comment: Host function in the CUDA context is a function that runs on the CPU (host) and not the GPU (device).

Comment: Obviously, but you are asking in the context of Python, so did you mean a Python function or a compiled C++ function? (the answer about cudaLaunchHostFunc is 99% certainly no)

Comment: I would like to callback a Python function.

Comment: You obviously can't do that. That would imply the CUDA driver could run python code, which is plainly not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to the CUDA C++ function `CUresult cuLaunchHostFunc(CUstream hStream, CUhostFn fn, void* userData)` in one of the Python libs (PyCuda, Numba, ...)?

Not in either of those two. None of the driver API based frameworks for CUDA I am aware of exposes `cuLaunchHostFunc` (PyCUDA, Numba, JCUDA).

> I want to schedule a Python host function asynchronous in a stream that runs after a kernel and memory copy has been taken place

Nothing in the native CUDA driver API could ever support that. Tensorflow and Pytorch both have elaborate execution pipelining and callback mechanisms at a Python level which *might* get you something functionally similar to what you envisage. But it won't be done at a CUDA level, it will be at a higher level of abstraction.